# which user's privileges python program uses to execute command via subprocess?

Tags: python, ubuntu, subprocess

I have stabled password less login between two ubuntu system then I run following command

```
$scp file user@hostname2:/tmp/
```

it works fine and I got file transferred without asking for password.
however when I try to execute the same through following python statement-

```
subprocess.check_output(['scp', file, r'user@hostname2:/tmp/'])
```

I am not able to copy files to remote computer, so I am bit curious about which user's privileges python program uses to execute command via subprocess ?

How can I debug such programs ?

Comment: "I am not able to copy files to remote computer," Why not? What happens?

Comment: Is `file` the name of the file or the variable which holds this name? Because, normally `file` is a builtin used to open a file. This might be a source of error.

Comment: Possibly ssh is not able to find your private keys, since the shell is not active in your command.

Comment: @glglgl: thanks for quick reply I am not sure about what happened, Thats what I am trying to figure out :0

Comment: @glglgl file I used as example here, its actual file name in my program

Comment: @PavanGupta But the question remains: do you use a string or a variable? COmpared with your initial example, it should be `'file'` instead of just `file` in the 2nd example. `file` refers to a name in Python - which may or may not be assigned anything useful - `'file'` is the string containing the word `file`.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: how can I activate shell in my command ? like this subprocess.check_output(['scp', file, r'user@hostname2:/tmp/'], shell=True)

Comment: @glglgl: I am using variable(named e2e_build) in my program